# How to for-loop tf.strings?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I have created a list of paths to my image dataset:

```
list_train = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(TRAIN_DIR + '/*/*'))
```

I want to for-loop this list to convert it to (image, label) pair. I want to use a function from the TensorFlow website:

```
def get_labels(file_path):
    #convert the path to a list of path components
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
    #my class directory is the second to last
    return parts[-3] == CLASS_NAMES
```

But this function does not accept the 'list_train' dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that I should not add anything to this function. This function is fed into another one:

```
def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  return label
```

And then we use it the following way:

```
labeled_dataset = list_train.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

The whole process is explained very well [here:](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images)